# Curvature of a curve of intersection of two surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

If the surface $S_1$ intersects the surface $S_2$ along the regular curve $C$, then the curvature $k$ of $C$ at a point $p \in C$ is given by $$k^2\sin ^2\theta=\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2-2\lambda_1\lambda_2\cos \theta$$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the normal curvatures at $p$, along the tangent line to $C$, of $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, and $\theta$ is the angle made up by the normal vectors of $S_1$ and $S_2$ at $p$.

I am hoping to see a proof of this statement. We have defined the normal curvature to be $\lambda=k\cos\theta$.

I would begin the proof as follows. By our definition, we have that $\lambda_1=k\cos\theta_1$ and $\lambda_2=k\cos\theta_2$, where $\theta_i$ is the angle between the normal vector of $C$ and the normal vector of $S_i$. Then, $\theta=\theta_1+\theta_2$. We then compute: $$\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2-2\lambda_1\lambda_2\cos \theta=$$$$k^2\cos^2\theta_1+k^2\cos^2\theta_2-2(k\cos\theta_1)(k\cos\theta_2)\cos\theta=$$$$k^2(\cos^2\theta_1+\cos^2\theta_2-2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2\cos\theta)$$ Then, it remains to show that $$\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta_1+\cos^2\theta_2-2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2\cos\theta$$ Is this correct? If so, where would I go from here?

Comment: @JohnHughes I haven't attempted to prove it. It isn't a problem to turn in or anything. I'm just curious.

Comment: A good first step would be to determine whether the $\theta$ in your displayed formula has anything to do with the $\theta$ in your definition of normal curvature (i.e., to clarify the question so that it's actually meaningful). My next step would be to look in, say, do Carmo or Millman and Parker's differential geometry books, because this is just the sort of thing they cover (albeit sometimes in the exercises, with a bit of a hint to get you started).

Comment: @JohnHughes This is actually an exercise in do Carmo's book. That's where I saw it. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Note that doCarmo has a detailed hint at the back of the book. This is a tricky problem I probably wouldn't think to approach "correctly."